# How to limit the number of lines for zsh 'cd -' completion?

Tags: zsh

Zsh's directory history is very useful. However, after wandering among many directories, it's annoying because too many lines are printed. How to limit the number of the lines to 10 or so, and print only the most recent directories? Please note that I set `AUTO_PUSHD`, `PUSHD_IGNORE_DUPS` and `PUSHD_MINUS` options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parameter `DIRSTACKSIZE` to limit the number of directories on the directory stack.

Just set

```
DIRSTACKSIZE=11
```

somewhere in your `~/.zshrc`. This will limit the number of directories shown when completing `cd -` to the last 10 directories, as the current directory is also on the stack but not shown for completion.